# How upload video on server(Android)?

Tags: upload, retrofit

Sorry for my english. I have some instruction for upload video on server. Its looks like this:

```
POST https://dev.test.one/api/videos/create
params:
data: {
   'players': '1,2,3' 
   'comment': 'Text' (> 5400)
   'file_name': ' '
   'file_full_name': ' '
    'file_name_without_storage':  ' '
    'file_type': ' '
    'file_disk': ' '
}
```

server developer the next few days will not be available( 
In android i use retrifilt for upload video, but i have error. I cant understand it error my(in android side) or it server error(in server side)

Bellow my code(interface):

```
@Multipart
@POST("/api/videos/create")
Observable<UploadVideoResponse> uploadVideoTest(@Header("Authorization") String userToken,
                                                @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params,
                                                @Part MultipartBody.Part video
                                                );
```

Bellow i create data:

```
File videoFile = getFile(pathVideo);

        Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("players", toRequestBody("101"));
        map.put("comment", toRequestBody("test comment"));
        map.put("file_name", toRequestBody(videoFile.getName()));
        map.put("file_full_name", toRequestBody("dev.test.one/storage/tmp_user_101/" + videoFile.getName()));
        map.put("file_name_without_storage", toRequestBody("dev.test.one/tmp_user_101/" + videoFile.getName()));
        map.put("file_type", toRequestBody("video-mp4"));
        map.put("file_disk", toRequestBody("s3"));

//create video data
 RequestBody videoBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/*"), videoFile)
MultipartBody.Part video = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("video", videoFile.getName(), videoBody)
```

From server i have error:

```
 ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in file /var/www/vhosts/test.one/dev.test.one/app/Http/Controllers/VideoController.php on line 445
```

Comment: The error does not do anything with android, I guess you should check the server/php code.

Comment: ask you backend developer.

Comment: @NoumanCh He is on vacation(( I think about may be i need my `map` add to key `data` in instruction all patams in key `data`

Comment: in server it parse like this `request[data][players]`